# How to format and use a BitLocker encrypted drive?

Tags: encryption, usb-flash-drive, format, bitlocker

I started the encryption process on my blank 64GB USB stick.

The process ran for about 12 hours and stuck at 21%. I paused the BitLocker encrypting process and restarted my computer.

And then I can't unlock the drive using neither the password nor the recovery key. It's it's saying "The password enter is incorrect".

I think the encryption process might had been corrupted.

I'm now trying to format the drive and use it; however, every formatting software I try tells me that the drive is write protected.

This is the result of the command `manage-bde -unlock f: -pw`.

[image]

I also tried to clear out the WriteProtect flag; however, it did not help as the USB was never marked as write protect.

[image]

How do I format and make use of my USB stick again now?

Answer (score 0):

Run the diskpart clean command when the bitlocked usb drive is selected as the active drive.

1. Open a command prompt as administrator
2. Type **Diskpart**
3. Type **List Disk**  to view all available disks.
4. Type **Select Disk #,** where # is the number of the drive you want to clean. You'll get a confirmation that Drive # is selected.
5. Type **Detail Disk**  to view detailed information on the selected disk to verify that the correct disk is selected. If you need to select another disk, repeat steps 3 & 4.
   The next step will destroy all data on the selected drive so proceed at your own risk.
6. Type **Clean**  to completely clean the drive.

You can now close the Command Prompt window and use Windows disk management to reformat/repartition your troublesome drive.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490893.aspx for additional information on using DiskPart.

Comment: Diskpart can seem like a complicated tool to run. Could you write out the steps OP should take to perform this?

Comment: Tried Jim Nielsen suggestion. It did not hep to resolve the issue. This is the out put of the clean command in disk part "DiskPart has encountered an error: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error. See the System Event Log for more information."

Comment: Baring a hardware error, try and give GParted a go - create a dban live bootcd via http://dban.org/

Comment: Jim Nielsen, I tried to use GPart in live boot of Ubuntu to format the drive and it's saying the /dev/sdb is read only. I then tried "sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb" but the issue remain unchange.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a low level format tool: http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-LLF-Low-Level-Format-Tool/

Comment: This low level format uilt. did not help. I already tried that every early on.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a number of the items / actions suggested but nothing worked.
Also I couldn't reformat the USB stick as it was 'write protected'. Even a low level formatting tool did not work (but only displayed the error it was write protected again).

When inserting the disk in a machine, I got the Bitlocker popup again if I wanted to ENCRYPT using bit locker or continue with an unencrypted disk. 
I first tried to select using it as unencrypted disk but after this, I was not able to format the disk :-(

Then I tried the option to encrypt the disk, as I hoped this might complete the encryption process and enable the disk again. Unfortunately I then received the message 'The drive cannot be encrypted because the file system is not supported.'

I inserted the USB stick into **another** machine/laptop.
Then when inserting the USB stick I got the Bitlocker popup again asking me if I would like to encrypt or use the disk unencrypted. Now I have chosen for using the disk unencrypted. Then I received the popup if I wanted to format the disk which I did and hurraah... I was able to access the disk again. Unfortunately I lost the content but the (in my case 500 GB disk) was usable again.

Hope this helps.